# What's the best Async/Await approach using Mongoose + Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I'd like to know if this kind of async/await approach with mongoose is correct. I still need to use .exec and then returning the promise with mongoose or I can leave things like this. Here my code snippet:

This is the user controller for example:

```
/* Func to update one user by id */
    const updateUser = async (id, user) => {
    const filter = {_id: id};
    const update = {name: user.name, email: user.email};
    const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: true});
    return result;
   };
```

This is the route:

```
/* PATCH update user passing the id in params */
router.patch('/list/:id/update', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await usersController.updateUser(req.params.id, {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    res.status(data ? 200 : 404).json({
      result: data,
      message: 'User updated',
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
      result: e.toString(),
    });
  }
});
```

Is this approach correct using mongoose or I need to use the async calling .exec().then().catch() after the query?

Answer (score 1):

According to [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await?), as far as functionality is concerned, these two are equivalent. However, they recommend using the `exec` because that gives you better stack traces:

```
const doc = await Band.findOne({ name: "Guns N' Roses" }); // works

const badId = 'this is not a valid id';
try {
  await Band.findOne({ _id: badId });
} catch (err) {
  // Without `exec()`, the stack trace does **not** include the
  // calling code. Below is the stack trace:
  //
  // CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "this is not a valid id" at path "_id" for model "band-promises"
  //   at new CastError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
  //   at model.Query.exec (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4331:21)
  //   at model.Query.Query.then (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4423:15)
  //   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  err.stack;
}

try {
  await Band.findOne({ _id: badId }).exec();
} catch (err) {
  // With `exec()`, the stack trace includes where in your code you
  // called `exec()`. Below is the stack trace:
  //
  // CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "this is not a valid id" at path "_id" for model "band-promises"
  //   at new CastError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
  //   at model.Query.exec (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4331:21)
  //   at Context.<anonymous> (/app/test/index.test.js:138:42)
  //   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  err.stack;
}
```